# Wordpress sidebar disappearing to the bottom in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, wordpress

Oh dearie me, I've had quite the two days looking at this but still no joy!

In Firefox and Chrome, this sidebar seems to be absolutely fine, displaying on the right as it should. In IE, however, it disappears to the bottom. I've tried debugging both the sidebar html and the css associated with it but to no avail.

Here's the site page:

I've made that post nice and small with no comments to show it's not a content image too big or such pushing it down.

Many many many thanks in advance for this!

Comment: In IE9 it all works, even if I switch to IE7/IE8 modes.

Comment: Also, why do you have the menu twice in your HTML, one time hidden?

Comment: i don't see that I'm afraid, I just see it once on my browser! Also, I'm using Internet Explorer 6 which doesn't work..

Comment: oh yes, i do have it twice there..I'll delete that other one..do you see my problem in internet explorer 6 though?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've sworn to myself I'd never use IE6 again in my life. Can't help you mate.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that theme uses .png images, which are not supported under IE6: [IE6 png fix - Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&q=IE6+png+fix&btnG=Search)

Another issue is that theme itself, as side from the .png images, may simply not work under IE6. If you're beginning with Wordpress and browser compatibility, ask the theme developer if the theme supports IE6.

IE6 is an ancient browser, and if you're trying to support it for your viewers, that requires work. If you use IE6 yourself, upgrade. Only around 5% or less of the world uses IE6 anymore due to modern web requirements and security issues.

Comment: The theme provides a blank CSS file to accomodate for ie6 so I'd assume there must be some sort of workaround to fit it for all browsers. The png issue actually stopped my heading showing for a while until I realised what was happeneing but I'm not sure how that would effect the menu on the right at all. The site is aimed at an older crowd, most of which will probably have an older browswer!

Comment: "...Most of which will probably have an older browser!" Sorry, but that doesn't make any sense. Most IE6 users, statistically, are some government offices and users in China. It has nothing to do with age. Do you and your potential viewers a favor and find a ready made theme that supports IE6, or decide not to support IE6 with what you are working with right now.

Comment: The solution was adding float:right;margin-right: 100px; to the sidebar element.